# Node.js setTimeout not exiting

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I'm writing a program that will try to solve a hard problem, but with a limit on the CPU time to spend, and trying to implement this with a setTimeout that exits the program after a certain time has passed, but nothing is happening when the time runs out. Boiling it down to a simple test case:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    process.exit(1)
}, 10)
while (1) {}
```

Instead of exiting after ten milliseconds, the above just stays hung.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `setTimeout` will run when the next free cycle comes along. `while (1)  {}` consumes all free cycles.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ah! Okay, so what is the best way to make a Node program exit after a certain time has elapsed, even if the main loop is still consuming all free cycles?

Comment: You would have to add something to the loop that checks the time elapsed and exits. Like set a variable to `Date.now()` before the loop. Inside the loop, subtract that variable from `Date.now()` and compare the result. If you're truly looking at values as small as 10 ms, I might use something like `performance.now()` or something with similar high precision, as `Date.now()`'s precision is around 10 ms.

Comment: Here is great talk on event loops -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&vl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript is asynchronous, which means one task at a time. JS will only switch to another task if the current task is finished or requiring additional operations (waiting for response, I/O operations etc.)

as while loop is never finishing and does not require another operations, it will just run forever and never switches to setTimeout.

more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop